# Does anybody build the lastest sawfish version on lastest ubuntu dist?

Tags: 13.04, compiling, emacs

I want to run sawfish with emacs, but I find it that the default sawfish wm is too old, I try to build it from scratch, but I failed. so any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and follow the instructions provided here: http://sawfish.wikia.com/wiki/Compilation_from_source

How exactly does it fail when you tried to build it before?